# How to filter custom post by rating star

Tags: rating

First user fill this custom comment form.

[image: first step]

This is my meta_key i want that i want to  fetch.
for every comment there are 10 rating.

[image: meta_key]

I want to make below rating filter.But don't know how to start.

[image: final output]

This is what  i tried yet.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 2 );

function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved  ) {

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );

    if( empty($comment) ) {
      return;
    }

    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

    $post_comments = get_comments( ['post_ID' => $post->ID ] ); 

    $meta_value = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID);

    d($post);

    // d($post_comments);
    d($meta_value);

    die;
}

function d($data) {
  echo '<pre>', print_r($data), '</pre>';
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I created a post meta and save it in updated rating average every time a comment is posted.

Now  want to make a filter as shown in above image, when any user click on checkbox against number of stars data must be filtered , and show those custom posts have average = chosen number of stars.

Answer (score 0):

I have create custom code for rating not for post type may be this code help you.

Step One:- Template file

```
    <!-- begin content -->
    <div id="content-wrap" class="top_pad review-planner" >         
        <div class="review-block">
            <div class="container">
            <h2><?php echo get_field('sub_title'); ?></h2>
            <div class="all-list" style="display:none;">
            <?php if(get_field('list_title')) { ?>
                <span class="title"><?php echo get_field('list_title'); ?></span>
            <?php } ?>  
            <ul class="list-item">
                <li class="service"><span>Service:<i></i></span></li>
                <li class="service2"><span>Uitsraling:<i></i></span></li>
                <li class="service3"><span>Ligging:<i></i></span></li>
                <li class="service4"><span>Eten&drinken:<i></i></span></li>
                <li class="service5"><span>Parkeren:<i></i></span></li>
                <li class="service6"><span>Prijs/kwaliteit:<i></i></span></li>
            </ul>
                <a class="reservBtn"><span>Schrijf een review</span></a>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>  


        <div class="user-reviews">
        <div id="ajaxData">



        <?php query_posts('post_type=reviews&showposts=-1');
                    if (have_posts()) : $i =1; while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );           
                ?>
            <div class="publish-review">
            <div class="icon" style="background:url(<?php if($url) { ?><?php echo $url; ?><?php } else { ?><?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ic.png<?php } ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;" >

            </div>              
            <div class="text-right">
            <h2><span><?php the_title(); ?></span> <cite class="rating"></cite> <i>9,7</i><small><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></small></h2>                
            <div class="desc">
                <p><?php echo get_field('description'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <?php if(get_field('service_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service">Service: <i><?php echo get_field('service_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  
                <?php if(get_field('uitsraling_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service2">Uitsraling: <i><?php echo get_field('uitsraling_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  

                <?php if(get_field('ligging_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service3">Ligging: <i><?php echo get_field('ligging_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  

                <?php if(get_field('eten&drinken_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service4">Eten&drinken: <i><?php echo get_field('eten&drinken_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  
                <?php if(get_field('parkeren_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service5">Parkeren: <i><?php echo get_field('parkeren_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  
                <?php if(get_field('prijskwaliteit_rating')) { ?>
                    <li class="service6"> Prijs/kwaliteit: <i><?php echo get_field('prijskwaliteit_rating'); ?></i></li>
                <?php } ?>  

            </ul>

            </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?> 

    </div>
        </div>


    </div>




<?php include 'reviewform.php'; ?>      

<!-- finish content -->
```

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('.header-wrap').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.all-list').fadeIn();
    jQuery('#content-wrap').trigger('click');
}, 1000);

jQuery('.review-block .all-list ul.list-item li').each(function() {
    var ffc = jQuery(this).find('span i').text();


    if (jQuery(this).find('span i').text() == "NaN") {

        jQuery(this).hide();
    }
});


jQuery('#content-wrap').click(function() {
    var url = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/loadData.php";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: "",
        my_option: 'sucomp',
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#ajaxData').html(data);
            var szs = jQuery('.user-reviews .publish-review').size();
            var szs2 = szs * 10
            serv = [];
            serv2 = [];
            serv3 = [];
            serv4 = [];
            serv5 = [];
            serv6 = [];
            var a1 = 0;
            var a2 = 0;
            var a3 = 0;
            var a4 = 0;
            var a5 = 0;
            var a6 = 0;
            jQuery('.user-reviews .publish-review').each(function(m) {
                var comvar = 0;
                var common = [];
                jQuery(this).find('.text-right ul li').each(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv.push(ths);
                    }
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service2')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv2.push(ths);
                    }
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service3')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv3.push(ths);
                    }
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service4')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv4.push(ths);
                    }
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service5')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv5.push(ths);
                    }
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service6')) {
                        var ths = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                        serv6.push(ths);
                    }

                    var ths2 = jQuery(this).find('i').text();
                    common.push(ths2);


                });
                common.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                    comvar += parseInt(ele);
                });
                comvar2 = comvar / 60;
                coml2 = comvar2 / 100 * 1000;
                console.log(coml2);

                jQuery(this).find('.text-right h2').find('i').text(coml2.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));

                var pars = parseFloat(coml2);
                var divd = pars / 100;
                var runds = divd * 1000;
                var pieces = runds.toFixed(0);

                rund = pieces;
                //alert(rund);  
                function addScore(score, $domElement) {
                    jQuery("<span class='stars-container'>")
                        .addClass("stars-" + score.toString())
                        .text("★★★★★")
                        .appendTo($domElement);
                    jQuery("head").append(jQuery('<style>.stars-' + rund + ':after { width:' + rund + '%; }</style>'));

                }

                addScore(rund, jQuery("#fixture-" + m));



            });
            serv.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a1 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp1 = a1 / szs2;
            tot1 = sp1 / 100 * 1000;

            serv2.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a2 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp2 = a2 / szs2;
            tot2 = sp2 / 100 * 1000;

            serv3.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a3 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp3 = a3 / szs2;
            tot3 = sp3 / 100 * 1000;

            serv4.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a4 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp4 = a4 / szs2;
            tot4 = sp4 / 100 * 1000;

            serv5.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a5 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp5 = a5 / szs2;
            tot5 = sp5 / 100 * 1000;

            serv6.forEach(function(ele, key) {
                a6 += parseInt(ele);
            });
            sp6 = a6 / szs2;
            tot6 = sp6 / 100 * 1000;

            jQuery('.review-block .all-list ul.list-item li').each(function() {
                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot1.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }

                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service2')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot2.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }

                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service3')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot3.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }

                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service4')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot4.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }

                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service5')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot5.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }

                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('service6')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('i').text(tot6.toFixed(1).replace(".", ','));
                }


            })




        },
        complete: function() {
            jQuery('.review-block .all-list ul.list-item li').each(function() {
                var ffc = jQuery(this).find('span i').text();


                if (jQuery(this).find('span i').text() == "NaN") {

                    jQuery(this).hide();
                }
            });

        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

})

Comment: Add js to below php code )